# Multiple Chi-squared tests

Tags: r, chi-squared

I am trying to show there is a difference between the survival rates of different classes in the Titanic data in r.  I am using the chi-squared via  `prop.test` but the result I get makes no sense.  There is a clear greater survival of  the first class compared to the others.

```
ship=data.frame(Titanic)
byclass = xtabs(Freq ~ Class + Survived, data = ship)


i_will_survive = as.vector(byclass[c(1:4),2])
total = as.vector(byclass[c(1:4),1]) + as.vector(byclass[c(1:4),2])
survival_rate = i_will_survive/total
```

```
> prop.test( survival_rate, total )

    4-sample test for equality of proportions without continuity correction

data:  survival_rate out of total
X-squared = 1.285, df = 3, p-value = 0.7327
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
sample estimates:
      prop 1       prop 2       prop 3       prop 4 
0.0019218935 0.0014527547 0.0003571171 0.0002706757 

Warning message:
In prop.test(survival_rate, total) :
  Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

What does this error message mean?

I think I need to run this again but do it so that I compare crew vs first class, then third vs first then second vs first then crew vs second and so on.  With 4! total out puts then I could display the chi squared values as a heat map with a Bonferroni corrected alpha value of 0.05/(4!).  Is my reasoning sound or have I over complicated things?

Comment: the first argument should be a count vector, `prop.test(i_will_survive, total)`, you should read the docs. also, `?pairwise.prop.test` would be useful to you

Comment: when I run it properly I get a result that makes sense> prop.test( i_will_survive, total )

 4-sample test for equality of proportions without continuity correction

data:  i_will_survive out of total
X-squared = 190.4, df = 3, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
sample estimates:
   prop 1    prop 2    prop 3    prop 4 
0.6246154 0.4140351 0.2521246 0.2395480

Comment: @rawr but I still think I should be running it individually as well, because while this shows there is a difference between groups it does not show what each one contributes.

Comment: If you have questions about using statistical methods to test an hypothesis, you should ask your question at [stats.se]. Stack Overflow is best for specific programming questions. Just because you are using R for your calculations doesn't make this a programming question necessarily.

Comment: OK thanks will do.